# Connect and create MySql database on AWS using PHP Admin

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin

Im trying to connect MySQLWorkbench to a AWS Bitnami EC2 image. In order to do this I have to create a MySQL database on the machine image first but I cant do this as I dont know how to connect PHPmyadmin to the machine image. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PhpMyAdmin is a web application, you access it from your browser, typing something like this:

```
http://server_url/phpmyadmin
```

If, for example, the server is on your own machine use this:

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

then if a password is setted you have to do a login in order to access phpmyadmin's administration page, here you could create a new database

[wikipedia on PhpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin)